# Why is my DrawableLeft doesn't appear the same on different device?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[image: Screenshot from Samsung Galaxy S6 edge+]

[image: Screenshot from Samsung Galaxy S6]

I dont know why Galaxy S6 doesn't recognize my .xml page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/arrowindidown"
        android:width="10dp"
        android:height="10dp"
        />
</layer-list>
```

Normally it will resize the image (the arrow) into 10dp as it appears in my Galaxy S6 edge+

(First screenshot is from my Samsung Galaxy S6 edge+)

(My homepage layout)

```
<!-- non-scrolling top pane -->
<LinearLayout
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="10">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo_home_id"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:background="@drawable/logo"/>
</LinearLayout>

    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/viewFlipper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="35">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/picture3"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/picture"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/picture2"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/picture4"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image5"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/picture5"
            android:onClick="onButtonClick" />
    </ViewFlipper>

    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/viewFlipperText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7">

        <TextView
            android:background="@drawable/border3"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Programme" />

        <TextView
            android:background="#404040"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="FIFOG classics" />

        <TextView
            android:background="#404040"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Palmares" />

        <TextView
            android:background="#404040"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Cairo time de Amir Ramses" />

        <TextView
            android:background="#404040"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Ahlam Mosteghanemi Présidente d'honneur du FIFOG 2016" />

    </ViewFlipper>

    <LinearLayout
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <Button
            android:background="@drawable/arrowotherside"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:onClick="onButtonClick" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ViewFlipper
                android:id="@+id/viewFlipperDot"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="7dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/c1"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="7dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle2"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="7dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle3"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="7dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle4"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="7dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle5"/>



            </ViewFlipper>

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:background="@drawable/arrowside"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
            android:text=""
            android:onClick="onButtonClick" />
    </LinearLayout>


<!-- scrolling bottom pane -->
<ScrollView
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="33">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ExpandableListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/expandableListView" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
    <TextView
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:text="© FIFOG Mobile Application"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

(My Group Layout - for my Expandablelistview)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/group_indicator_selector"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:id="@+id/parent_txt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please help.

Comment: Why do you need to hardcode the width and height? What size is the original image? Why don't you use the standard 24x24 size for such drawables?

Comment: @Vucko I've already done that. But the image quality is not really that good...